# Did [juno] that this tag had many usages?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-disambiguation

I encountered the [juno](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/juno) tag.

According to its tag wiki, it is about OpenStack Juno. However, it is also used for questions about the Juno IDE for the Julia language and questions about Eclipse Juno.

I suggest the following disambiguation:

- openstack-juno
- julia-juno

There already is a tag for [eclipse-juno](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/eclipse-juno), so I'll see if I can do some re-tagging there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the Julia questions, the [juno-ide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/juno-ide) tag was *already* present, with a tag excerpt of "The Juno IDE for the Julia programming language". Therefore the usage of [juno](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/juno) for questions related to the IDE was incorrect. [juno](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/juno) certainly is ambiguous and was being used for multiple reasons. As there were only 33 questions in the tag, I checked all the questions in the tag, and retagged them correctly. The following were the different questions I found:

- Julia IDE Juno, which had to be tagged [juno-ide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/juno-ide) instead. (10, 1 too broad)
- Eclipse versions 3.8-4.2, which had to be tagged [eclipse-juno](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/eclipse-juno) instead. (5, 2 off topic, 1 too broad)
- OpenStack Juno, for which the tag had to be used. (16)

Some rare usages were related to:

- Jupyter Juno - [How to import Pandas into Jupyter notebook on iPad through Juno?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51335475/how-to-import-pandas-into-jupyter-notebook-on-ipad-through-juno)
- Juno Arm Development Board - [Cross-compiling for arm64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50491623/cross-compiling-for-arm64)

where I just removed the tag. As there were just single occurrences, I did not create a new tag for them.

I finally renamed [juno](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/juno) as [openstack-juno](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/openstack-juno), and added it as a synonym to prevent it from being recreated.